# git - changed file summary like svn diff --summarize/svn status from console (no gitk)

Tags: svn, git, diff

`svn diff --summarize` shows the changes at the file level for a commit. Output it something like:

```
 M   modified-foo.bar
 D   deleted-file.bar
 A   new-file.bar
```

Similar to svn status, but for commits. I would be happy with output similar to git status, but for a particular commit instead of the working copy.  I know I could fire up gitk to see such a summary, but I want it in a shell.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
git diff <commit> --name-status
```

Comment: By the way I was using --name-only until now. This is better. :) I also had to look at the help.

Comment: `git status` also produces something similar

Comment: `git status -s` and `git status --porcelain` is similar but they are only usable for working copy.

Comment: Doesn't that show all the changes between `<commit>` and the current working tree?

Comment: Yes, but that is what @noah wanted to know: _Similar to svn status, but for commits._

Answer (score 13):

Try this:

```
git show <commit> --name-status
```

I think `show` is probably what you want rather than `diff`. `show` shows the changes of that commit. `diff` shows all the changes between the specified commit and the current working tree, unless you specifically give it a commit range.

Sometimes I like to see some graphical metrics of changes:

```
git show <commit> --stat
```

(Although that doesn't clearly indicate file additions and deletions distinctly from modifications.)